# autocomplete does not work in dynamically loaded inner div of parent page?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

autocomplete does not work in dynamically loaded inner div of parent page?
i have a button in parent page,when i click that then another html is loaded in a empty div of parent page but that loaded another page is having auotcomplete drop down but that autocomplete does not work in that loaded form.
My code is :
`another.html`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.autocomplete.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#course").autocomplete("includes/addcandidate/get_course_list.php", {
width: 260,
matchContains: true,
selectFirst: false
    });
});
</script>
<td align="left"></td>
```

---

`Parent.html`

```
<input type="button" class="button small green" value="getCourseList" onclick="getCourseList();">
<div id = "getCourseList_innerDiv"></div>
```

when i open this page in browser like `http://localhost/parent.html`
it open with button name of `getCourseList` when i press that button then another.html is loaded in the div `getCourseList_innerDiv.Upto`  now working fine but issue is that when another.html is loaded that inner div that autocomplete does not work so please any one can help me out i will greatfull to you...please

Answer (score 0):

Add your autocomplete handler to the document.ready like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#course").autocomplete("includes/addcandidate/get_course_list.php", { width: 260, matchContains: true, selectFirst: false }); }); 

});
```

else add the autocomplete handler on to some live click function like

```
$("#course").live('click',function(event) {}
```